# Custom SQL statement (CASE )in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am creating Android app using parse back end. Parse has very great documentation, but I couldn't find how to do custom sql query. 
What I want is:

```html
SELECT F.status, U.username, U.email
FROM users U, friends F
WHERE
CASE

WHEN F.friend_one = '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_two = U.user_id
WHEN F.friend_two= '$user_id'
THEN F.friend_one= U.user_id
END

AND 
F.status='1';
```

Particularly I can not figure out how to do CASE statement in PARSE.